# Зачем нужен обьект SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, ado.net

сколько не читал мсдн так и не понял зачем при заполнении datagridview прописывать еще и SqlDataAdapter а DataTable недостаточно? Может вопрос глупый но я хочу понять а не просто писать код, что бы работало.

Comment: Если кратко, DataAdapter обеспечивает выполнение запросов к базе и трансляцию результатов в DataTable.

Comment: но запрос можно выполнить и без DataAdapter. например добавить строку в бд или прочитать содержимое столбца.

Comment: С самим DataTable да, можно что угодно руками сделать. А если нужны результаты запроса от сервера? там может быть не одна таблица, может быть нужно отправить обновленные данные из DataTable обратно, можно конечно все руками, но зачем?

Comment: DataTable это просто класс для работы с данными. Получение, обновление и т.д. в его обязанности не входят

Comment: Если будет время попробую вечером написать подробно, если ни кто раньше не отпишется.

Comment: а для чего тогда DataTable ? вот положим мне нужно заполнить таблицей из бд датагридвью на форме. какова логика этого процесса? SqlConnection - создает соединение, SqlCommand - отправляет SQL запрос по указанному соединению, SqlDataReader - читает полученные данные. а DataAdapter и DataTable  то что делают?

Comment: DataReader и DataAdapter делают грубо говоря одно и тоже, только ридер читает результат построчно, а адаптер целиком, а DataTable и DataSet просто оболочка для представления табличных результатов запроса к базе. Своего рода кэш данных базы на стороне клиента.

Comment: Извините, не совсем понимаю что значит целиком. DataReader и  DataAdapter взаимозаменяемы?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56713/discussion-between-rdorn-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала обратимся к документации. Ссылки привожу на русские страницы, но перевод там автоматический, и мне не нравится, поэтому цитата будет оригинальная.

[**SqlDataReader**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Provides a way of reading a forward-only stream of rows from a SQL Server database.

[**SqlDataAdapter**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents a set of data commands and a database connection that are used to fill the DataSet and update a SQL Server database.

По сути оба класса предоставляют доступ к данным БД, но немного по-разному.

`SqlDataReader` предоставляет строго последовательный доступ и читает данные небольшими порциями, что позволяет работать даже с огромными таблицами без риска получить исключение по таймауту. Но на этом его достоинства заканчиваются, больше он ничего не умеет.

`SqlDataAdapter` предоставляет богатый интерфейс для автоматического заполнения `DataTable` и `DataSet`, а также предоставляет средства синхронизации данных между `DataSet` и БД, но при этом, на практике, довольно капризно относится к слишком большим наборам данных, т.к. пытается получить их целиком. Если набор данных превышает некоторый объем (зависит от настроек соединения, задержек в сети, загруженности сервера и т.д.) то адаптеру не хватит времени на его получение и будет выброшено исключение.

Универсального рецепта что использовать тут нет, так же как при работе с файлами. Где-то выгоднее использовать ридер, где-то адаптер.

`DataTable` и `DataSet`, согласно документации и практическому применению, представляют кэш данных БД в памяти клиента. `DataSet` состоит из набора `DataTable` и дополнительно может содержать подробности реляционной модели
кэшированных данных.

`DataTable`, в частности, может использоваться как `DataSource` для контролов вроде GridView, ListView и д.р. предназначенных для отображения массивов данных.